# HTML 5 Canvas Event Handler Working?

Tags: html5-canvas

In W3schools it written that there is "No support for event handlers".But when i append onclick to canvas its working .Why ?

```
<html>
<body>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid    #c3c3c3;" onclick="alert(1)">
</canvas>
<script>
```

Comment: The html canvas element **does support mouse events**. It does not (by default) support other events like keydown, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because w3school content should be taken with a grain of salt. They are correct and provides nice examples for some things, but are directly wrong on other things - and does not have a proper mechanism to tell/correct them.

Canvas do support events both as subscriptions (using `addEventListener()`) as well as as direct callbacks (such as `canvas.onclick = ...`).

For keys you need to use `tabIndex` to "activate" the ability to catch focus. While it has focus it can also receive key events (you can in any case receive those from the `window` object).

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var out = document.getElementById("out");

canvas.addEventListener("keydown", output);
canvas.addEventListener("keyup", output);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouse);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", mouse);
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouse);
// ... etc

function output(e) {out.innerHTML = e.type + ": " + e.keyCode}
function mouse(e) {out.innerHTML = e.type + ": x=" + e.clientX + " y=" + e.clientY}
```

```css
canvas {background:#ddd}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" tabIndex="0" width=400 height=150></canvas><br>
<output id="out"></output>
```